# Cosmos DB - patching a document after deleting it still finds (and upserts) the document?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

As the title says:

First I go to the Azure Portal, find the record in the collection and press manual button for delete:
[image]

Then I run select query again to make sure the record was deleted. It seems that it was indeed deleted:
[image]

Then I go and try to patch deleted record with a new value for one of the fields using `PatchItemStreamAsync()` operation:
[image]

Instead of getting an error that document was not found, the same document has been successfully patched (and thus recreated) with the new value set.
I can see it if I search the collection again:
[image]

Mind you this happens even a few minutes after deleting the record.

This seems to happen when I have `"indexingMode": "none"` for testing.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Below sample item is stored in Azure Cosmos DB Container:

```js
{
   "id": "1",
   "name": "Balaji",
   "age": 24,
   "section": "B1"
}
```

I have deleted the sample item from the container then executed the below code and the output is "Failed to patch item".

`PatchItemWithStreamAsync()` method is used in the below code, it converts the list of patch operations to a stream because the Cosmos DB `PatchItemStreamAsync()` method expects a stream as input.

Once the patch operations are converted to a stream, the method calls the Cosmos DB `PatchItemStreamAsync()` method to patch the item. The `PatchItemStreamAsync()` method returns a `CosmosResponseMessage` object, which contains information about the success or failure of the patch operation.

Below code uses a `Using` statement to dispose of the stream object when it is no longer needed.  In your code Using statement does not explicitly dispose of the stream object.

Below is the code with changes and shows an output as Failed to patch item when it is deleted manually in Azure Cosmos DB.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string endpoint = "*****";
    string key = "*****";
    string databaseId = "FirstDb";
    string containerId = "newCont";

    CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpoint, key);

    Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

    string itemId = "1";
    PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("1");

    List<PatchOperation> patchOperations = new List<PatchOperation>
    {
        PatchOperation.Set("/section", "B1")
    };

    PatchItemRequestOptions requestOptions = new PatchItemRequestOptions
    {
        EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false
    };

    var response = await PatchItemWithStreamAsync(container, itemId, partitionKey, patchOperations, requestOptions);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item patched successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to patch item.");
    }
}

static async Task<CosmosResponseMessage> PatchItemWithStreamAsync(
    Container container,
    string documentId,
    PartitionKey partitionKey,
    List<PatchOperation> patchOperations,
    PatchItemRequestOptions requestOptions)
{
    using (var stream = ToStream<IReadOnlyList<PatchOperation>>(patchOperations))
    {
        using (var responseMessage = await container.PatchItemStreamAsync(
            id: documentId,
            partitionKey: partitionKey,
            patchOperations: patchOperations,
            requestOptions: requestOptions))
        {
            var result = new CosmosResponseMessage
            {
                IsSuccessStatusCode = responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode,
                ActivityStatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode,
                ErrorMessage = responseMessage.ErrorMessage
            };
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Failed to patch item.
```

Comment: Thank you for recreating this scenario. In my code the 2nd using statement disposes of the stream object. Have you tried setting "indexingMode" to "none"?

Comment: Yes, I tried with "indexingMode" to "none" in settings.

Comment: That means it must be something local to my environment. Very strange...